# node.js and processing data AFTER redirect

Tags: node.js, express

I have an app written in Node.js + Express to process incoming data and redirect customers somewhere else. The thing is processing can take a while (mostly stats related, so GEO-specific data + DB lookups) so is it conceptually correct to capture necessary headers (for data processing), send 301/302 header and **THEN** process captured data? The goal is to redirect customers as fast as possible and not let them wait when the processing is done as **processing itself is irrelevant for the redirection** (we can assume destination URL is fixed).

E.g.:

```
...
app.get('/click', function(req, res, next) {
    // capture some incoming data
    var ua = req.get('User-Agent');
    var ip = (req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
            req.connection.remoteAddress || 
            req.socket.remoteAddress;
    // redirect
    res.redirect(302,"http://www.google.com");
    // heavy processing on incoming
    processData(ua, ip);
});
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine, assuming processData is asynchronous, which it almost certainly already is, to avoid blocking the the Express server. As your system scales, you should consider switching to dispatching the processData functions to a queue where they can be handled by additional machines. Check out http://learnboost.github.io/kue/ and https://github.com/resque/resque .

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, It almost similar to using "setTimeout" on post pone the operation.

```
"Node.js" is single threaded
```

But You have to remember "Node.js" single threaded. So This operation "processData(ua, ip)" is possibly **block subsequent request** from same or different HTTP client. If "processData(ua, ip)" don't include any file,network, database or any port read/write operations, then there is no way to get advantage of **Non-Blocking IO**. So even your approach is working well in local environment, it is not good fit for production.

```
Alternate way
```

So to do heavy process, create child process with your input and let it finish. The better thing is, you have to keep your main process(the process which is listening port) in less work load as much as possible.

Comment: To be clear, change the last line to setTimeout(function(){processData(ua, ip)},0); This will allow the express function to return without waiting on processData. As long as the work done is mostly io bound you are probably good to go. If there's a large javascript computation inside processData you need to look at the alternatives.

Comment: Any clue how can I fork to child processes?

Comment: You can do i by using "forever module" which is one of my pick.